# Reading JS cookie in .htaccess and setting redirect rules based on cookie content

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess

How can I update my rules in `.htaccess` to read a user side cookie properly and redirect based on that?

Basically I have a cookie called `userstate` and it's content is abbreviation of us states. For example in this case it is `AL` (cookie been set by user first visit radio options) now I would like to redirect user to `www.domain.com/al/index.html` if the cookie been set, otherwise redirect to home directory as  `www.domain.com/index.html`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} lang=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?lang=%1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*userstate.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /login-error/set-cookie-first.cgi [NC,L]
```

Comment: Why are you checking for `lang=` when setting a cookie with the name `userstate` ?

Answer (score 0):

You either redirect when cookie is set

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*userstate.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.domain.com/al/index.html [NC,L]
```

Or if you want to redirect if the cookie is not set

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*userstate.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.domain.com/index.html [NC,L]
```

You only need one though. Choose the other one as standard :)

> Documentation :
>
> https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess-fresh/#Set_Cookie_based_Requested_directory
>
> https://aloneonahill.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners/